# Livewire Dynamic Routes from MQSL returns 404 but Laravel is just fine

Tags: routes, dynamic

```
$page= Page::where('slug', '=', $url)->first();
$page= (empty($page)) ? null : $page->toArray();

if ($page!= null) {
    if ($page['fileName'] == 'homepage') {
        Route::get('/', Homepage::class);
    } else if ($page['fileName'] == 'listAds') {
        Route::get('/{slug}', ListAds::class)->where('slug', '.*');
    }
`
```

I've found the problems.
Looks like livewire couldn't use routes like above example (using if and fetch from database), Livewire returns 404 Error message when I clicked on the "paging" next button
But when I use manually like :
`Route::get('/', Homepage::class);`
it looks good.

Can anyone help me for the solutions using dynamic routes from database?
Thanks